# Jqgrid keep focus on current cell when using editrules

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jqgrid

First, I'm going to be submitting a couple of different questions that relate to the code snippet posted here.  So, if you see other questions and think "hey, that's a duplicate, I've seen that code" it really isn't.  I want to be sure to credit each answerer for the distinctly different questions.
Here's one:  I have the following jqgrid, and I'm trying to change the masking from "__" to "00" when the user only enters the first half of the field.  The method gets called, the value changed, but it still displays the old value.  I'm using jqgrid version 4.2.
Grid:

```
WorkSchedule.prototype.init = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.jqgridParms = {
            datatype: "local",
            height: 'auto',
            width: 700,
            colNames: ["Week", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Total"],
            colModel: [// very much dummy stuff here.
                        {name: "Week", index: "Week", width: 50, editable: false },
                       { name: "Sun", index: "Sun", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                           dataInit: function(elem) {
                               $(elem).mask("99:99");
                           }
                       }, align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                       },
                        { name: "Mon", index: "Mon", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                            dataInit: function(elem) {
                                $(elem).mask("99:99");
                            }
                        }, align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                        },
                        { name: "Tues", index: "Tues", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                            dataInit: function(elem) {
                                $(elem).mask("99:99");
                            }
                        },
                            align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                        },
                        { name: "Wed", index: "Wed", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                            dataInit: function(elem) {
                                $(elem).mask("99:99");
                            }
                        },
                            align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                        },
                        { name: "Thurs", index: "Thurs", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                            dataInit: function(elem) {
                                $(elem).mask("99:99");
                            }
                        },
                            align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                        },
                        { name: "Fri", index: "Fri", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                            dataInit: function(elem) {
                                $(elem).mask("99:99");
                            }
                        },
                            align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                        },
                        { name: "Sat", index: "Sat", width: 85, editable: true, edittype: "text", editoptions: { size: 20, maxlength: 30,
                            dataInit: function(elem) {
                                $(elem).mask("99:99");
                            }
                        },
                            align: "center", formatter: timeEntryFormat, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: validHourEntry }
                        },
                        { name: "WeekTotal", index: "WeekTotal", width: 55, editable: true, align: "center" }
                      ],
            multiselect: false,
            caption: "Manage Work Schedule",
            rowNum: 10,
            cellEdit: true,
            gridComplete: function() {
                calculateTotal();
            },
            beforeSaveCell: function(rowid,cellname,value,iRow,iCol) {
            formatFromMask(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol);
            },
            afterSaveCell: function() {
                calculateTotal();
            },
            cellsubmit: "clientArray"
        }
}



 function formatFromMask(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
            if (typeof value !== "undefined") {
                value = value.replace(/_/g, "0");
return value;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the simple answer, which is to set the mask to "00:00".  It brings up a separate issue, but solves the problem here.